# Test the proper functioning of a FastAPI instance

Tags: python, python-requests, postman, fastapi

I want to test the correct functioning of a FastAPI instance with a `POST` operation. The first step is to test the operation as if it were a normal Python function, as follows:

```
import uvicorn
from fastapi import Request, FastAPI
from typing import List, Optional
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI()

class Company(BaseModel):
    id: int
    name: str
    vat: str
    website: Optional[str] = None

@app.post("/processes/new/")
def new_process(id_user: int, companies: List[Company], stop_words: str, blacklist: List[str]):
    # some code
    return companies[0].dict() # just an example of output

if __name__ == "__main__":
    id_user = 1
    companies = [Company(id=1, name="ABC srl", vat="0123456789", website="https://www.abc.it/"), Company(id=2, name="XYZ srl", vat="9876543210", website="https://www.xyz.it/")]
    stop_words = "a;the;and"
    blacklist = ["https://www.def.it/", "https://www.ghi.it/"]
    print(new_process(id_user, companies, stop_words, blacklist))
```

Everything works fine. Now I make the following changes to be able to test the API:

```
@app.post("/processes/new/")
async def new_process(id_user: int, companies: List[Company], stop_words: str, blacklist: List[str]):
    # some code
    return companies[0].dict() # just an example of output

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn(app, host="127.0.0.1", port=8000)
```

I have two questions:

1. If I wanted to test the operation on the browser what could I do? Should I use something like Postman? And if so in what format should I enter the data for the test?
2. If, on the other hand, I wanted to test the functioning through a `POST` request? Should I use the `requests` module? And in this case in which format should I enter the input data?

Comment: Have you seen the TestClient that has been made for testing the FastAPI? https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/testing/

Answer (score 0):

You can use both Postman or a script with requests, but there is a faster way to test your APIs manually. FastAPI has built-in Swagger(OpenAPI) support, so just go to 127.0.0.1:8000/docs and test your API endpoints.

You can check for more detail: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/first-steps/?h=openapi#interactive-api-docs